# Loading screen in TabLayout

Tags: android, tabs, loading

I have a tablayout with several activities in it, and changing from a tab to another one takes a couple of seconds (because it needs lots of datas). While it is loading I want a dialog appear that indicates the loading. I created a very simple dialog with a progress bar, but I dont know when to call it and when to dismiss it.

```
 loading = new Dialog(FatActivity.this);
        loading.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        loading.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_loading);
        loading.show();
```

Every tab shows an activity, but if I put it in the onCreate() method (right after it, so to the first row), it doesnt appear, only after the activity loaded. So where should I put it, or if it is a wrong approach of making a loading screen then how should I do this? I was thinking about this, because I just have to call it then dismiss it at the end of the onCreate(). And since it is a tablayout there is no onclicklistener on the tabs, so I cannot use it either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) best way to display Loading screen...

```
onCreate()
{
    dialog.show();
    new LoadData().execute(null);
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------     
    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Boolean> {
         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
             // your code to load data here <------
             return true;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
```

Comment: what part of this is the part of onCreate() ?

Comment: Note that if you aren't passing anything in the execute of an AsyncTask (like you do here, with a hardcoded null). You should set the first type of AsyncTask to Void and the statement would be just execute().

Comment: I would use it in a bigger activity and I cant solve the next problem: "Only the original thread that created a view hiearchy can touch its views". Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As Gtumca said use an AsyncTask, but I want to report you that the TabHost is deprecated because with the last versions of android Fragments and FragmentActivity have replaced it.
In this way your code becomes more comprehensible and well divided instead of TabHost.